# Should foreign key and linking column considered normal column with special data type in Kdb+?

Tags: database, time-series, kdb

From the doc, we can define foreign key and linking column as below:

```
// for linking column
t1:([] c1:`sym?`c`b`a; c2: 10 20 30)
t2:([] c3:`sym?`a`b`a`c; c4: 1 2 3 4.)
update t1link:`t1!t1.c1?c3 from `t2

// for foreign key
ff:([sym:`A`B`C] eps:1.2 2.3 1.5;bps:2.1 2.5 3.2)
fkt:([] s1:`ff$())
```

And how we define the column type within table creation:

```
// create table with column type defined
tb:([] c:`int$())
```

Is it reasonable to refer, that after the column name declaration (like `c1:`), the symbol and operator always define the type of the column ?

I mean,

- a **foreign key** could be considered as normal column whose domain is limited to the referenced column.
- a **linking column** could be considered as normal column whose type is related to target table by notation `` `t1! ``  specifying the situation.

**Is this assumption reasonable** ?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a table you should type your columns if you can.
But it is possible and sometimes necessary to used an untyped list `()` for a column.

You need this when making compound columns (lists of lists):

```
q)t:([] stringCol:())
q)meta t
c        | t f a
---------| -----
stringCol|
q)type each flip t
stringCol| 0
q)`t insert enlist 3 4 5?\:.Q.a //insert some random string data
0 1 2
t
q)stringCol
---------
"lfu"
"wgby"
"fenjc"
q)meta t //Capital letters like 'C' in meta denotes nested lists
c        | t f a
---------| -----
stringCol| C
q)type each flip t
stringCol| 0
```

Be cautious when working with untyped columns and relying on `meta` as it only checks the first row. An untyped column can have a mix of datatypes

```
q)`t insert enlist 3 4 5?\:100 //Add some long data type J
3 4 5
q)t //The table column is a mixture
stringCol
--------------
"emb"
"dnth"
"isbuc"
24 60 69
8 62 95 59
82 47 26 93 38
q)meta t //meta only checks the first row, it assumes all are 10h
c        | t f a
---------| -----
stringCol| C
q)distinct type each t`stringCol //To check all rows in a column
10 7h
```

An untyped list can have it's type promoted if a vector is appended to it:

```
q)t:([] untypedCol:())
q)t insert enlist `a`b`c
0 1 2
q)meta t
c         | t f a
----------| -----
untypedCol| s
q)type each flip t //The column is now a symbol vector type 11h
untypedCol| 11
q)`t insert enlist 1 2 3 //You can no longer insert other types
  [0]  `t insert enlist 1 2 3
          ^
```

Foreign key columns and linked columns are just special types of lists which follow similar rules to above

```
q)ff:([sym:`A`B`C] eps:1.2 2.3 1.5;bps:2.1 2.5 3.2)
q)fkt:([] s1:())
meta ff
c  | t f a
---| -----
sym| s
eps| f
bps| f
q)meta fkt  //Untyped column, no key
c | t f a
--| -----
s1|
q)`fkt insert enlist `ff$`C`B`A
0 1 2
q)meta fkt //Symbol type column with foreign key
c | t f  a
--| ------
s1| s ff
```

Feel free to join the KX Community which has lot's of discussion areas:

- https://community.kx.com/

The KX Academy also have lots of interactive tutorials:

- https://kx.com/academy/

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to point out here, in relation to your "could be considered as normal column", is the following:

Although the meta of your linked-column table shows as a long (aka "j", aka type 7h), the actual datatype is an enumeration (type 20h)

```
q)meta t2
c     | t f  a
------| ------
c3    | s
c4    | f
t1link| j t1
q)
q)type each flip t2
c3    | 20
c4    | 9
t1link| 20
```

So there's a subtle difference there which makes it not quite a "normal column". Similarly for the foreign key column:

```
q)fkt:([] s1:`ff$`C`B)
q)meta fkt
c | t f  a
--| ------
s1| s ff
q)type each flip fkt
s1| 20
```